# Phaser IO Not Rendering in Capybara Selenium Functional Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, phaser-framework

I've created a Rails app with a Phaser IO HTML 5 game.  Now I'd like to use Capybara to write a test that verifies that the game is loaded in the browser.  I don't want to test the specifics; I just want to validate that the game canvas was inserted into the DOM.  [This is what I have so far](https://github.com/wedding-website/wedding_website/blob/broken-selenium-test/spec/features/save_the_date_spec.rb):

```
describe 'The Save The Date Game', :type => :feature, :js => true do
  it "should render on the page", :driver => :selenium do
    puts " driver is #{Capybara.current_driver} "
    visit url_for save_the_date_path
    expect(find('#phaser-game > canvas')).not_to be_nil
  end
end
```

The issue I'm running into is that the game isn't rendering the Selenium controlled instance of Firefox.  This is odd because the game does load when I visit the page outside of Capybara/Selenium, when I test the page manually.  How can I make the game render in the test environment?